# Не пойму, что за ошибка Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Здравствуйте, господа.
Опубликовал приложение для альфа-тестирования. И вот какую ошибку получил в процессе тестирования от пользователей, которые работают на **Android 4.4**, на других версиях 4.0-4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0 такой ошибки нет:

> *****               ***** Build fingerprint:
>   'lge/g2_spr_us/g2:4.4.2/KOT49I.LS980ZVC/LS980ZVC.1394331950:user/release-keys'
>   Revision: '10' pid: 32015, tid: 32015, name: my_app  >>>
>   my_app.my_app <<< signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2
>   (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 65e3e988
>       r0 417f5028  r1 417f2de0  r2 00000000  r3 417f2de0
>       r4 6095dec8  r5 6a8287e0  r6 0000ffff  r7 603fee48
>       r8 6a8287e8  r9 6a8549c0  sl bebbe0c8  fp 603fee48
>       ip 00000000  sp bebbdf08  lr 41737ba7  pc 65e3e988  cpsr 00070010
>       d0  4003eb324851a871  d1  3f2ba7fc32ebe597
>       d2  028c038b048a0589  d3  600201d00e44018e
>       d4  0069005600200074  d5  0061005000770065
>       d6  0049007200650067  d7  006300690064006e
>       d8  4980000000100000  d9  0000000043d20000
>       d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
>       d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
>       d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
>       d16 e1a01007e1a00006  d17 e1a07000eb000000
>       d18 e34600ace3030668  d19 e3500f00e5900000
>       d20 ea0000001a000000  d21 e59dc000e1a00007
>       d22 e58ec000e59de004  d23 e8bd9fc0e28ddf2c
>       d24 0028002700250026  d25 0029002a002a0029
>       d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
>       d28 001e001d001c001b  d29 0020001f001d001e
>       d30 002a002a002a002a  d31 0000000000000000
>       scr 80000017
>
> backtrace:
>       #00  pc 0002a988  
>       #01  pc 00054ba3  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmRemoveFromReferenceTable(ReferenceTable*, Object**, Object*)+4)
>       #02  pc 0002a984
>
> code around pc:
>       65e3e968 65e3e97c ffff0002 00010000 60ab04e0
>       65e3e978 60ab04e0 00000000 00080000 65e3d330
>       65e3e988 00000010 00000000 65429c60 65e3e968
>       65e3e998 65e3e9a8 00000119 65e3e9c8 65e3ea20
>       65e3e9a8 6176616a 746e695f 706f7265 696e6a5f
>       65e3e9b8 5f766e65 6f726874 62ce0077 00000000
>       65e3e9c8 65e3e9f0 0000002a 80000012 00000004
>       65e3e9d8 00000000 6a84dec8 6a84dee8 6a84df08
>       65e3e9e8 6a84da28 00000000 03020c16 000202f0
>       65e3e9f8 03290000 0d000000 394b14f0 00000010
>       65e3ea08 00f00cf0 00000004 00013925 267a0000
>       65e3ea18 00002a09 00000001 00000004 65e3e958
>       65e3ea28 60769538 65e3e938 60941a80 00000006
>       65e3ea38 00000007 00000008 645de7f0 00000001
>       65e3ea48 00000001 ffffffff 00000002 ffffffff
>       65e3ea58 ffffffff 65ed3380 0000000b 0000001e
>
> code around lr:
>       41737b84 b5106803 e0033b04 3b046804 d0034294
>       41737b94 4618428b 2000d2f8 b510bd10 f7ff4604
>       41737ba4 b160ffef 1f136822 ebc06023 ea5f0c03
>       41737bb4 d00502ac 00921d01 ef90f7ca bd10e000
>       41737bc4 bd102001 f046b10a 4770bed7 4604b5f8
>       41737bd4 460d4608 f9c6f7fd 46296922 6960182f
>       41737be4 1a121b7e d8114296 f7ff4632 6965ffeb
>       41737bf4 692619ad d01342b5 46314628 1b752201
>       41737c04 ffe0f7ff 1b416920 e0096121 ffdaf7ff
>       41737c14 69636921 1aca4620 463a18a9 ed90f7d9
>       41737c24 bdf84620 43f0e92d 4d2f4691 4a2f460f
>       41737c34 447db08f 58a9461e 4688680c 4604940d
>       41737c44 492bb928 4a2b2005 447a4479 4825e007
>       41737c54 d1074284 20054928 44794a28 f7ca447a
>       41737c64 e034eeae a8014621 feb6f7fd 68224b24
>       41737c74 f8d158e9 42a240c4 4922d104 4479a801

Понятия не имею где копать, гугл не дал результатов. Какие будут идеи?

Comment: Идея - искать результаты в гугле на английском языке. Пример запроса: "android 4.4 signal 11 code 2 fault addr". Вот что нашёл на SO. МБ вам подойдёт http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас гляну